# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: poo, php5, php7, sql

Estoy estudiando php, intentando hacer una consulta a la base de datos utilizando POO, pero no me sale. Me aparece el siguiente mensaje al ejecutar el index.php:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp64\www\CursoPHP\POO\consultaProductos.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\CursoPHP\POO\index.php(7): consultaProductos->getProductos() #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\CursoPHP\POO\devuelveProductos.php on line 14

He buscado ayuda por internet y no logro solucionarlo. El código lo tengo en 4 arcnivos php así:

**config.php**

```html
   <?php


    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');

    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

    define('DB_NOMBRE', 'prueba');

    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');



?>
```

**conexion.php**

```html
<?php
    
    require "config.php"; //invoca constantes que se encuentran dentro del archivo de su nombre

    class conexion{ //crear la clase para la conexión
        
        protected $conexionDB; //propiedad de la clase
        
        public function connect(){ //inicio constructor
            
            $this->conexionDB=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NOMBRE);
            
            if($this->conexionDB->connect_errno)
            {
                echo "Falló al conectar a MySql: " . $this->conexionDB->connect_error;
                
                return;
            
            } //Fin constructor
            
            $this->conexionDB->set_charset(DB_CHARSET); //línea que llama al código de caracteres latinos
        }
    }


?>
```

**consultaProductos.php**

```html
<?php

    require "conexion.php"; //invoca el archivo donde se encuentra la conexión

    class devuelveProductos extends conexion{ //utiliza la herencia de una clase padre
        
        public function devuelveProd(){ // inicio constructor
            
            parent::__construct(); //llama al constructor de la clase padre
        } //fin constructor
        
        public function getProductos(){ //método de la clase
            
//El error se genera en esta línea de código
            $resultado=$this->conexionDB->query('SELECT * FROM ARTÍCULOS'); 
            
            $productos=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI); // línea que almacena la consulta en un array
            
            return $productos; // devuelve la variable
        }
    }
    



?>
```

**index.php**

```html
<?php
    
    require "devuelveProductos.php"; //invoca la(s) que se encuentran dentro del archivo php

    $productos=new devuelveProductos(); // Instancia que llama a la clase padre

    $array=$productos->getProductos(); //almacena todos los datos en la variable $array

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    
    <h2>Resultado de la búsqueda con POO</h2>
    
    <div class='datagrid'><table>
    <thead><tr><th>Código Artículo</th><th>Nombre Artículo</th><th>Sección</th><th>Precio</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Importado</th><th>País Origen</th></tr></thead>
    
<?php
    
    foreach($array as $elemento){?>
        
    <tbody><tr><td>

<?php
    echo $elemento['CODIGOARTICULO'] . "</td><td>";

    echo $elemento['NOMBREARTICULO'] . "</td><td>";
        
    echo $elemento['SECCION'] . "</td><td>";
        
    echo $elemento['PRECIO'] . "</td><td>";
        
    echo $elemento['FECHA'] . "</td><td>";
        
    echo $elemento['IMPORTADO'] . "</td><td>";
        
    echo $elemento['PAISORIGEN'] . "</td></tr></table>";
        
    echo "<br>";
        
    echo "<br>";
        
    }
    
?>
        
    </tr></tbody>
    </table></div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="volver" name="atras" onClick="history.back()" />
    
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan facilitar.

---

Mikel, me podrías explicar detalladamente como se utiliza correctamente el constructor. Estoy haciendo un MVC con la misma tabla, y me arroja el mismo error. No logro encontrar el hilo que hace que funcione. Estos son los archivos.

el archivo de conexion, está en la carpeta controlador con el archivo connect.php

```html
class conectar{
    
    //creamos la clase donde se almacenará el método de conexión
    public static function conexion(){
        
        try{
            
            $conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=prueba', 'root', '');
    
            $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            
        }catch(Exception $e){
            
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
            
            echo "Linea de error: " . $e->getLine();
        }
        
        return $conexion; //se devuelve la variable $conexión al terminar de revisar el método
    }
}
```

La consulta a la db se hace desde la carpeta modelo con este archivo. productosModelo.php

```html
//creamos la clase que realizará la consulta en la base de datos
class productosModelo{ //es una buena práctica que se siga la nomenclatura tradicional en la que se nombra la clase y a la capa que le corresponde
    
    //Creación de dos variables que solo se usaran en esta clase. Una es la conexión a la base de datos y la otra es la consulta
    private $db;
    
    private $productos;
    
    public function _construct(){
        
        require_once("modelo/connect.php");
        
        //espefica la variable donde se almacenará la conexión y se llama la función donde está la conexión función::método()
        $this->db=conectar::conexion();
        
        //Creamos un array para almacenar la consulta de el la variable productos
        $this->productos=array();
        
    }
    
    public function getProductos(){ //es buena practica agregar el get en el nombre de la clase
        
        //la variable $consulta, ejecuta la sentencia SQL
        $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ARTÍCULOS");
        
        //este bucle recorrera el array de la sentencia SQL realizada donde
        while($filas=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            
            $this->productos[]=$filas; //al recorrer las filas de la sentencia, se almacenan en la variable $filas
        }
        
        return $this->productos; //devuelve los productos que se encuentran dentro de la variable productos.
    }
}
```

En la carpeta vista tengo el archivo productosView.php, donde imprime el array que fue almacenado en productosModelo.php.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ver Productos</title>
    <link href="../../Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="datagrid">
        <table><thead><tr><th>NOMBRE ARTÍCULO</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
    
<?php
        foreach($matrizProductos as $registro){ //metemos el array en una tabla
            
            echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["NOMBREARTICULO"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
    
    
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

en la carpeta controlador tengo el archivo productosControlador.php

```html
<?php

require_once("modelo/productosModelo.php"); //invocamos el productos modelo

//ejecutamos el método que se encuentra en la clase dentro del archivo productosModelo.php
$productos=new productosModelo();//se crea una variable para llamar al constructor de la clase

$matrizProductos=$productos->getProductos(); //se crea una variable para llamar al método de la clase 

require_once("vista/productosView.php"); //invocamos el productos view

?>
```

y todo es ejecutado desde el index.php

```html
<?php

require_once("modelo/productosModelo.php"); //invocamos el productos modelo

//ejecutamos el método que se encuentra en la clase dentro del archivo productosModelo.php
$productos=new productosModelo();//se crea una variable para llamar al constructor de la clase

$matrizProductos=$productos->getProductos(); //se crea una variable para llamar al método de la clase 

require_once("vista/productosView.php"); //invocamos el productos view

?>
```

cuando ejecuto el index.php, me muestra el mensaje: `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp64\www\CursoPHP\MVC\modelo\productosModelo.php on line 26`

Les agradezco la ayuda

Comment: intentaste validar el contenido de todo lo que estas pasando ? y de validar que llegue a los constructores?

Answer (score 0):

Tanto `public function connect(){` en `conexion.php` como `public function devuelveProd(){` en `consultaProductos.php` , deberían de ser `public function __construct(){` para evitar problemas con la nomenclatura del constructor.

El error que te esta dando es porque estas llamando al metodo `query()` en null; porque no has inicializado `$this->conexionDB`, seguramente porque al hacer `parent::__construct();` no habrá encontrado el constructor de la clase `conexion`.

Acostumbrate a hacer [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) para comprobar que las variables contienen lo que crees que deberían y que estan inicializadas cuando te dan esta clase de errores.

Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias Mikel por la ayuda. Ya lo he solucionado